# Styles defined in app.xaml doesn't take effect for the first time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I've global style defined in `app.xaml` like:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type xcdg:HierarchicalGroupByControl}">
                        <Setter Property="NoGroupContent" Value="Some content" />
                    </Style>
                </ResourceDictionary>
<!-- some more dictionaries here -->
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <local:AppBootstrapper x:Key="bootstrapper" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I need to set `NoGroupContent` for every datagrid in my application.
I am using `Caliburn.Micro` and showing my windows like:
    windowManager.ShowWindow(new MyViewModel());
in `MyView.xaml` (which is automatically attached to `MyViewModel` by `cm`) I have simple `xcdg:DataGridControl` nested inside `Window` control.

My problem is that the style defined this way doesn't have any effect for the first time, but it's working properly when I close and reopen window or open any other, similar window.

This problem doesn't occur when I define this style directly inside `xcdg:DataGridControl.Resources` but I have several windows and I would like not to repeat myself.

---

From my observations the same thing goes for any style defined this way and is not correlated with this specific control.

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Finally managed to track down the links I was talking about. Please see [here](https://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/workitem/244) (my CM issue report) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4811884/650012) (recommended SO Q&A). Meanwhile I'll remove my answer.

Comment: @AndersGustafsson: thank you very much, now everything's working just fine :)